# (Beginner) How to add a delete button to my index.php file that will delete categories from the database

Tags: php, html

```
<?php include 'view/header.php'; ?>
<main>
<h1>Menu</h1>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="product_manager">Product Manager</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="product_catalog">Product Catalog</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://localhost:8081/category_list.php">Categoy List</a>
        <a href="../category_list.php">Category List</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Add Option -->
<h1>Add Category</h1>
<form action="category_list.php" method="post">
    <label>Category:</label>
    <input type="input" name="categoryName" />
    <input id="btnAddCategory" type="submit" value="Add"/>
</form>

<!-- Delete Option -->
<h1>Delete Category</h1>
<form action="category_list.php" method="post">
    <input id="btnDelCategory" type="submit" value="Delete"/>
</form>

</main>
<?php include 'view/footer.php'; ?>
```

I am wondering if there is a way to add a delete button that will delete categories from the database. Would the layout be the same as my "Add Option"? Not looking for a complete answer but more of a tip to go off of. I've have been picking at it for a while just trying to make some more progression.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a *specific* programming problem, but we are not here to write code or design your system for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: _"Ignore the two category lists, I am keeping that there for a mental note for now."_ - Please don't use SO as a notepad. Edit the question to only include the code that's relevant to your issue, including your attempts to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood well, you want to deleted all your categories by clicking on a button. For your problem, you should have a separated action file (eg. `delete_categories.php`) to process the deletion operation.
If you want to delete a specific category you should have something like hidden HTML input which has category-id that you want to delete it.

Comment: Thank you, yes I have a bunch of seperate files. I have a database.php file, I got it to work withough having to use the MVC controller but I cannot seem to get the same result using it..